# what is alternative for select string_split('r,a,d,o',',') in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to convert a string into rows in MySQL.

select id from month_tab where name in (
string_split('jan,feb,mar,may')
);

In the above example, we need to return **string_split('jan,feb,mar,may')** as rows.
the final output should be like
select id from month_tab where name in ('jan','feb','mar','may')
);

Comment: You asked how to convert delimited string into rows - the first two duplicates answer the question. However, if you want to imitate in operator with delimited string, then see the 3rd duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `JSON_TABLE`

```
with cte as (
  select 'jan,feb,mar,may' as months
)
select month_tab 
from cte
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(months, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (month_tab TEXT PATH '$')) jsontable;
```